# NullPointerException when trying to add an object to a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, addition, priority-queue

i keep getting a null pointer exception when trying to add an object to a priority queue

i initialize the queue:

```
private PriorityQueue<NodeObject> nodes;
```

and here i try to add to it:

```
NodeObject childNode = new NodeObject(child, 1);
nodes.add(childNode);
```

why doesn't this work? i know my NodeObject is not null because i create it right before i add it.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't initialized the queue.

```
nodes = new SomePriorityQueue();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you forgot to initialize your priority queue `nodes`. Change it to:

```
private PriorityQueue<NodeObject> nodes = new PriorityQueue<NodeObject>();
```

Or explicitly allocate `nodes` (as in `nodes = new PriorityQueue<NodeObject>();`) in each of your constructors. Keep in mind that in Java, any type that isn't a primitive is actually an implicit pointer, so while the pointer `nodes` has been initialized to `null`, it has not been initialized to point to something.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually create a priority queue; `nodes == null`. This causes `NullPointerException` to be thrown when you try to invoke `nodes.add`.

The way to fix this is by actually constructing a `PriorityQueue<NodeObject>`, and assigning the reference to it to `nodes`. You can do this in the declaration as follows:

```
private PriorityQueue<NodeObject> nodes = new PriorityQueue<NodeObject>();
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### [JLS 4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5)

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a *default value* when it is created:
>
>   - For all reference types, the default value is `null`.

Comment: That's another problem entirely. Where do you get the error? What line? Give us the full exception message, and the line in the code where the message says the error comes from (and a few lines surrounding it for context). Simply instantiating a `java.util.PriorityQueue<E>` should not throw a `StackOverflowError`. Are you doing any sort of recursion too by any chance?